# Powershell remoting with V1

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0, powershell-remoting

Do you know of any good remoting solutions using powershell V1 (I know the V2 stuff is awesome, but my organization doesn't like using pre-release software).  I don't need anything spectactular, just a way to kick off powershell script on another box and get the results back when they're done.  I'm considering using sysinternals PSEXEC and export-csv/import-csv and just making something that works.  I'd rather have someone else do the work, though.

Comment: Lee Holmes has posted a solution using PSExec and xml (rather than csv)
http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/CategoryView,category,guide.aspx

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: 'Cuz I didn't think of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [great article](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/02/29/remoting-using-powershell-v1.aspx) up on the PowerShell team blog that describes how to get some basic remoting working in V1.

Basically, PS V2 uses Windows Remote Management (WinRM) under the hood. Winrs is the command line tool used to work remotely with machines.

This tactic that Jeffrey talks about uses WinRS and some PowerShell trickery to get remoting working in V1. Its not as slick as V2, but you can definitely get some basic stuff working with it.

Comment: IMO, this is the best native way. However, I think it only works with machines where WinRS is installed and running. i.e. limited to Vista and Server 2008. XP will not work as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I think PrimalScript's Remote Script Execution Engine would do what you're after. It does require a small service to be installed on remote computers, but you get unlimited licenses for that when you buy PrimalScript (Enterprise edition).

There's also a PSHRemoting project someone did.

N Software's NetCmdlets also come with a "PowerShell Server" (http://nsoftware.com/powershell/) which enables remoting.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PSExec successfully. You can also use WMI to kick off remote processes. [Here](http://blog.svenlandgraf.nl/?p=24) is an example.

Comment: Yeah...I've used PSExec as well, just didn't know if anyone had done the work to do powershell via psexec and get the results back as objects in powershell on the sending side.

Doesn't seem like it would be hard, just don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone else has done the work.

Comment: Also, Using WMI to start the process would probably be about the same as PSExec.  So I really don't have a preference there.  I thought of PSExec first since I had used it previously.

Answer (score 0):

Lee Holmes has posted a solution using PSExec and xml (rather than csv) http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/CategoryView,category,guide.aspx